# Query Flurry API from desktop java app

Tags: java, flurry

I have a few apps in flurry and want to write a desktop console program (in java) that queries the API for certain metrics.

The idea is that I run my java app and it pulls all the flurry metrics I want down.

I found the android and iOS and windows PHONE sdks but can't find a java library.

I tried googling but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the HTTP Client libraries in java to execute an HTML query to

```
http://api.flurry.com/appMetrics/Sessions?apiAccessCode=CODE&apiKey=APIkey"&startDate=DATE&endDate=DATE
```

This returns (almost instantly so watch out for the 1query/sec limit) JSON code that contains the requested metrics.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.